# why am I getting an error on calling clothing.getLastWornDate() method?

Tags: java, date, getter, localdate

I am working on a Java assignment for school. In this method, I am trying to save to a file as described by assignment, but I am getting an error when calling `clothing.getLastWornDate()` and am lost as to how to correct it.

```
/**
   * Saves all of pieces of clothing in this wardrobe to the designated file. Each piece of 
    clothing
   * in the Wardrobe is written on its own line, formatted as 

     description,brand,lastWornDate,timesWorn.
   * The date must be formatted MM/DD/YYYY.For example, lets say a piece of clothing had a  

     description
   * of "black t-shirt", brand of "Gildan", a lastWorn date of October 25th, 2023, and has been         
     worn
   * 15 times. Then the line in the text file is "black t-shirt,Gildan,10/25/2023,15"\n.
   *
   * Parameters:
   *     saveFile - the File that the information should be written to
   * Returns:
   *     true if the file saved successfully, false otherwise
   * @param saveFile
   * @return
   */
  public boolean saveToFile(File saveFile) {
    try {
      FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(saveFile);
      LocalDate dateFormat = LocalDate.parse(("MM/dd/yyyy"));

      for (Clothing clothing : wardrobe) {
        String formattedDate = dateFormat.format(clothing.getLastWornDate());
        String line = String.format("%s, %s, %s, %d\n", clothing.getDescription(), clothing.getBrand(),
            formattedDate, clothing.getNumOfTimesWorn());
        writer.write(line);
      }

      writer.close();
      return true;
    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
      return false;
    }

  }
```

Declaration of `Clothing.getLastWornDate`:

```
  public LocalDate getLastWornDate() {

    return lastWornDate;
  }
```

I am lost as to how to fix this.  Intellij is telling me to change the method header for getLastWornDate, but assignment write up is specific as to leave the header as `public LocalDate getLastWornDate()`.  Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: hi, please add some more details to your question. What is the error/Exception? Can you please post the entire class? The `clothing.getLastWornDate` in the middle don't make much sense.

Comment: [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: It looks like the line clothing.getLastWornDate is between two methods.

Comment: *LocalDate dateFormat = LocalDate.parse(("MM/dd/yyyy"));* -> `DateTimeFormatter dateFormat = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM/dd/yyyy");` as @BasilBourque said

Answer (score 2):

> `LocalDate.parse(("MM/dd/yyyy"))`

Invalid code.

You cannot parse a formatting pattern. I suspect you want to use `DateTimeFormatter` here.

> dateFormat.format(clothing.getLastWornDate());

Also invalid code.

You defined `dateFormat` as a `LocalDate` rather than as a `DateTimeFormatter`. The `format` method on `LocalDate` takes a parameter of type `DateTimeFormatter`, but you are passing a `LocalDate` object.

Programming by intuition is risky business. I suggest you instead try programming by documentation. Carefully **read the Javadoc** before coding. Also, search Stack Overflow as date-time handling in Java has been addressed many times already.

Tip: Compile and run your code often. Write the least code you can to be able to run successfully before adding more code.

Tip: Never store nor exchange date-time values textually in a localized format. Use only standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formats for that. Conveniently, the *java.time* classes use ISO 8601 formats by default when parsing/generating text.

---

Revise your code to be something similar to this:

```java
// Data
record Clothing( String description , LocalDate whenWorn ) { }
Collection < Clothing > wardrobe =
        List.of(
                new Clothing( "jacket brown" , LocalDate.of( 2024 , Month.JANUARY , 23 ) ) ,
                new Clothing( "jacket black" , LocalDate.of( 2024 , Month.JANUARY , 25 ) ) ,
                new Clothing( "pants white" , LocalDate.of( 2024 , Month.JANUARY , 22 ) ) ,
                new Clothing( "pants grey" , LocalDate.of( 2024 , Month.JANUARY , 23 ) )
        );

// Report
Locale locale = Locale.UK;
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDate( FormatStyle.MEDIUM ).withLocale( locale );
for ( Clothing clothing : wardrobe )
{
    System.out.println( "Description: " + clothing.description + " was last worn on " + clothing.whenWorn.format( f ) );
}
```

```
Description: jacket brown was last worn on 23 Jan 2024
Description: jacket black was last worn on 25 Jan 2024
Description: pants white was last worn on 22 Jan 2024
Description: pants grey was last worn on 23 Jan 2024
```